# Constructor overriding another constructor in same class: Error

Tags: c#, constructor, overriding

I have two constructors, in same class, with multiple arguments (c# on visual studio):

```
public class Example
{
 {
 public string arg1 { get; set; }
 public string arg2 { get; set; }
 public string arg3 { get; set; }
 public string arg4 { get; set; }
 public string arg5 { get; set; }
 public string arg6 { get; set; }
 }

public Example(string arg1, string arg2, string arg3){
this.arg1 = arg1;
this.arg2 = arg2;
this.arg3 = arg3;
}

public Example(string arg4, string arg5, string arg6){
this.arg4 = arg4;
this.arg5 = arg5;
this.arg6 = arg6;
 }
}
```

In a separate aspx.cs file, under protected string method, I'm calling these two constructor based on condition.

```
Example ExampleObj = null;

protected string Method(object sender, EventArgs e){

 if (condition){
  ExampleObj = Constructor2(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3, parameter4, parameter5, parameter6);
 }
 else
 {
  ExampleObj = Constructor1(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3);
 }

}
```

If condition is true, I want to call second constructor, with the arguments in addition to arguments in Constructor1. I think, I can say constructor2 overrides or extends the constructor1.
After all my research, I tried

```
public Constructor2(string arg4, string arg5, string arg6)
:this(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
 this.arg4 = arg4;
 this.arg5 = arg5;
 this.arg6 = arg6;
}
```

Still, I'm getting error 'an object reference is required' for arguments in this(). As per my requirements, I can't make my main method static. I found some solutions saying create instances or change to static, but I'm unable to apply that on my code (getting errors).

Also, I'm not getting it clear if I should state datatype in this() constructor. Please, help me if anyone knows the solution to this. I might be missing something.

Thanks!

Comment: Calling a member function `Constructor` does not make it a _constructor_ (that, according to C# syntax has to have the same name of the class). What you have are just two initialization methods. Call it directly `this.Constructor1(...)`. Oh...and change name! If, instead, you want to have two _real_ ctors then they must have different signatures (and you can call _the other one_ in the way you're doing)

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the question. I have constructor named same as the class.

Comment: @VertikaMisra: well, why dont ylou change the code instead of just writing _"this is just a blueprint of my code. I have constructor named same as the class"_?

Comment: Points you missed:
1) Constructor should have the same name as Class
2) Constructors can not exist with same parameter list(same amount of parameters and same types)
3) You missed "new" keyword when creating an object of type Example

Answer (score 2):

A valid constructor should have the same name as the class.

You can have 2 constructors but they need to have the same name and different parameter lists. Otherwise the compiler can't tell them apart when you use them.

This works Ok:

```
  class Example
  {
    public Example(string arg1)
    { 
      this.arg1 = arg1;
    }

    public Example(string arg1, string arg2)
        :this(arg1) 
    {
      this.arg2 = arg2;
    }
  }
```

Comment: In C# "[a] valid constructor [...] **must** have the same name as the class" FTFY

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers. Since, constructors seem to be fine, I tried declaring properties as static and don't know what I was doing wrong before, it worked. Now, the constructors are both good.But, when I'm calling the second constructor for object, it is saying 'Class does not contain a constructor with six arguments'. Is there a different way to call this constructor for object?

Comment: Hey, I was missing arguments from first constructor, into the second one:
public Example(*_string arg1,_* string arg2)

Answer (score 1):

The c# compiler can't distinguish between the two constructors since they have the same signature (method name, number and types of parameters). If you had a different number of arguments for each constructor, or if any of your arguments was of a different type, your code would compile.

I'm guessing you are looking for something like this:

```
public class Example
{
    public string arg1 { get; set; }
    public string arg2 { get; set; }
    public string arg3 { get; set; }
    public string arg4 { get; set; }
    public string arg5 { get; set; }
    public string arg6 { get; set; }

    public Example(string arg1, string arg2, string arg3)
    {
        this.arg1 = arg1;
        this.arg2 = arg2;
        this.arg3 = arg3;
    }

    public Example(string arg1, string arg2, string arg3, string arg4, string arg5, string arg6)
         : this(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    {
        this.arg4 = arg4;
        this.arg5 = arg5;
        this.arg6 = arg6;
    }
}
```